# How to read first, second,third word of a line from a file and use it in bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to read a line from a file, pick the words and assign it to the variables to be used later in the script

file.txt

A B C

A1 B1 C1

A2 B2 C2

I am writing a bash script that executes by taking arguments from the above file

```
Bash.script
input=/home/xyz/file.txt
while read -r line;
do
echo $line
export first=A
export second=B
export third=C
done
```

How do I pick the 1st,2nd and 3rd word and assign it to the variables as shown above?

Comment: `while read -r f1 f2 f3; do echo "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"; echo export first=$f1; echo export second=$f2 ; echo export third=$f3; done < "$input"`

Comment: That works for me. Thanks!